# Android App with system privileges accessing SD

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-permissions

I have a complex scenario. I have 2 apps that share the database of one of them. This is done by using the same "shared id" and it's working fine. However I also need to give one App system privileges to change the device time. This also works fine. The problem arise when I want to access the SD from that app. If I give system privileges to it, I cannot access the SD anymore (Is there a work around?). I thought about letting the other app do the job, however in order to access the database it should have the same "shared id", therefore it also should have system privileges.

Briefly I want the app to have system privileges and access the SD in the same time. I have another app that share the database.

One solution I found is to use ContentProvider, this way I can transmit the data to the other app (without sharing the same id) and handle the SD access there. However this approach would necessitate alot of modifications to the solution I already have, it's my a last resort. I also checked that it was possible to make the database public (Mode_world_read) but is now deprecated.

Is there other ways to overcome this limitation? One idea could be to save the database in a custom folder that the other app can access. Is this possible? Can an app access other folders on an Android device? Can I read from a database that is not in /data/data/{package name}/databases/ ? Bare in mind that the apps are private, they won't be on the app store, so there's no problem in giving system privileges.

Comment: Why can't system app access SD (card)? Does that imply that non-system apps can?

Comment: Yes they do. As for system Apps, I guess Android enforces this for security reason. (Dependence on SD is risky)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best (and proper) way to share database to other apps would be to expose data through content provider as you already figured out, otherwise you might have soon or later any synchronization problems, or case when both apps will try to modify DB file at once.

I'm not sure why you don't have SD access but sounds like you wan't to access private storage of another app, which is not normally possible?

> Can I read from a database that is not in /data/data/{package
>   name}/databases/ ?

Yes. `SQLiteOpenHelper` access DB through the context. To override DB path you can use `ContextWrapper` like:

```
public class TestContext extends ContextWrapper{
    public TestContext(Context base) {
        super(base);
    }

    @Override
    public File getDatabasePath(String name) {
        // name is passed here from SQLiteOpenHelper
        return new File("path to DB on SD card");
    }
}
```

Then when you will create DB helper, use that `TestContext` :

```
public class TestSQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public TestSQLiteHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(new TestContext(context), name, factory, version);
    }
}
```

When `TestSQLiteHelper` will try to access DB file, it will call `getDatabasePath()` where `File` with your custom path will be returned.